# Steps view or Timeline view in react native

Tags: react-native

I need a steps view or timeline view in which I need to track the order.

The is a view in `Steps` in Ant design for mobile, But in it, I am not able to increase the length of the tail. Any help will be helpful.[image]

code

```
<Steps progressDot current={0} direction="vertical">
      <Step
        title="Finished"
        description={
          <View style={{padding: 100}}/>
        }

      />
      <Step 
        title="Finished"
        description="This is a description. This is a description."
      />
      <Step
        title="In Progress"
        description="This is a description. This is a description."

      />
      <Step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." 

      />
      <Step title="Waiting" description="This is a description." 

      />
    </Steps>
  </View>
```

Comment: Which package did you use? If that's from scratch, share your Steps, step components

Comment: Ant design for mobile

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: https://github.com/24ark/react-native-step-indicator

As a bonus you will get indicator to the current step or any specific step you want.